# Show Hide div with css only (no input nor tabindex)

Tags: html, css

I've been searching for a while now and I can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

I need to do a hide/show functionality just with CSS. When `header.title` is clicked, I need the `div` to be shown, and when it is clicked again, it should disappear. 
For some (out of the topic) reasons I can't edit the HTML, so inputs or tabindex aren't an option.

```
<aside>
  <header class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    Some information here
  </div> 
</aside>
```

I don't even know if this is possible, if not, just tell me.

Comment: this sounds like js or jQuery, i've search a css solution too but there is realy no solution.

Comment: With `:target` pseudo (and a focusable link and a target `id`), it'd be possible to hide/show an element but that'd still not be a toggle (clicking twice wouldn't do the opposite of clicking once, it'd do the same thing). A `<button>` and JS is the right way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't permanently alter DOM elements with CSS only.  Hence, if the user moves their finger off the mouse, the style reverts.

Comment: I guess you're right, since no other options were offered.

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is  [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) CSS pseudo-class

```
<aside>
  <header class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    Some information here
  </div> 
</aside>
```

**Style:**

```
div[class=content]{
   display:block;
}

header.title:hover + div.content{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for , but you cant do this with only CSS.

As **user1167442** said You can't permanently alter DOM elements with CSS only. Here you need JQuery

```
 $("div.content").hide();
    $("header.title").click(function(){
        $("div.content").toggle();

    });
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/HuuLD/

**Note:** Don't forget to include Jquery library file

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use Jquery either :S I need just CSS.